# Атрибуты передаются как числа с плавающей запятой, тогда как их всегда следует передавать как строки

Tags: reactjs, typescript, nextjs

Все добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста с кодом. Мой бэкендщик переписывает сервер с Python на Rust, а этот язык не поддерживает строку. Поэтому передо мной вот такая задача: attributes передаются иногда как числа с плавающей точкой , а нужно чтоб всегда передовались ввиде строки. Подскажите пожалуйста где и что мне нужно дописать чтоб attributes привести к строке, чтобы всегда передавалась строка.

вот моя компонента:

```
import axios, { CancelTokenSource } from 'axios'
import dealTechBaseInstance from './dealTechBaseInstance'

const getSearchInstance = () => {
  let token: CancelTokenSource = null

  return async function (query: string, { variables } = { variables: {} }) {
    if (token) {
      token.cancel()
    }
    token = axios.CancelToken.source()
    try {
      const res = await dealTechBaseInstance({
        cancelToken: token.token,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {
          query,
          variables
        }
      })
      return res.data.data.search
    } catch (err) {
      if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
        return {
          isCancel: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const searchLaptops = getSearchInstance()

debugger

export async function search(
  query: string | string[],
  category: string,
  sortOrder: string,
  attributes: { [key: string]: any }[],
  page: number,
  pageSize: number,
  price: { min: number; max: number }
): Promise<any> {
  const data = await searchLaptops(
    `query search($query: String, $category: ID, $sortOrder: ID, $attributes: [SearchAttributeInput], $page: Int, $pageSize: Int, $price: MinMaxPriceInput) {
       search(query: $query, category: $category, sortOrder: $sortOrder, attributes: $attributes, page: $page, pageSize: $pageSize, price: $price) {
         debug
         maxPages
         numProducts
         products {
           productId
           title
           imageUrl
           newPrice
           details {
             text
           }
           imageUrl
           seller
           buyUrl
         }
       }
     }`,
    {
      variables: {
        query,
        category,
        sortOrder,
        attributes,
        page,
        pageSize,
        price
      }
    }
  )
  return data
}
```

Comment: «а этот язык не поддерживает строку» — это в смысле как?

Comment: Python поддерживает использование чисел в виде строк, а Rust - нет. Поэтому, если  я передам в Rust число в виде строки, я  не получу результата.